# How to get value from selected radio button from Angular 11 Form using Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

So I am trying to capture the value of my radio button whenever I submit my Bootstrap-based form. I have tried to use vanilla JavaScript to extract this value in my component.ts file, but I get a compile error in VSCode as:

> Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

**Browser:**
[image: Mac Browser View]

**TS:**
[image: signin.component.ts]

**HTML:**
[image: signin.component.html]

How can I get the value of this radio button in my form? I am very new to Angular, so I have been avoiding using ngModel so far because I am unsure if that will require me to set a new property within the TS file or add another import to that TS file. Any help with this functionality is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

```
const roles = document.getElementsByName("role") as NodeListOf<HTMLElement>;
```

you're strictly-typing the returned nodes to be of type **HTMLElement**. A radio button however is of type **HTMLInputElement**, so it correctly throws the error because a HTMLElement doesn't have a `.checked` property.

After changing the line to:

```
const roles = document.getElementsByName("role") as NodeListOf<HTMLInputElement>;
```

you can iterate over the nodes using your existing for-loop and get the nodes value using the `.value` property.

e.g.

```
for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
  let ele = roles[i];
  console.log(ele.value);
}
```

Comment: That fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: No problem Azhya - glad I could help! =)